How to configure the Rate Limiter of the StandardResilienceHandler
I'm writing an application that connects to another HTTP service. I want to rate-limit my outgoing requests to that external service.
Ideally, I want to use the standard resilience handler as documented here, to benefit from the configured best-practice defaults when it comes to resiliency.
services.AddHttpClient<ExternalServiceGateway>()
    .AddStandardResilienceHandler();

However, since I know that the external service is rate-limited to 120 req/sec, I want to apply a similar policy to my outgoing calls.
I can achieve this using a separately-configured ResiliencePipeline (see below), but I want to combine this with the AddStandardResilienceHandler(). Is there any way to achieve this?
var pipeline = new ResiliencePipelineBuilder()
    .AddRetry(new RetryStrategyOptions
    {
        ShouldHandle = new PredicateBuilder().Handle<RateLimiterRejectedException>(),
        Delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
        MaxRetryAttempts = 5,
        BackoffType = DelayBackoffType.Exponential,
        UseJitter = true
    })
    .AddRateLimiter(new FixedWindowRateLimiter(new FixedWindowRateLimiterOptions()
    {
       PermitLimit = 2,
       Window = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
    }))
    .Build();

Update: example code for problem/solution
I have published a minimal solution to experiment with this problem/solution here.

The AddStandardResilienceHandler has an overload where you can override each of the predifined strategies' options. This can be as simple as this:
.AddStandardResilienceHandler(options =>
{
    options.AttemptTimeout.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
});

The rate limiter override is a bit tricky. You have to acquire a lease like this:
.AddStandardResilienceHandler(options => 
{ 
    options.RateLimiter.RateLimiter = args => 
    {
        var limiter = new FixedWindowRateLimiter(new FixedWindowRateLimiterOptions()
        {
            PermitLimit = 2,
            Window = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
        });
        return limiter.AcquireAsync(cancellationToken: args.Context.CancellationToken);
    };
});


Update #1
As it was discussed in the comments section the above suggested solution does not work as expected. The main reason is that a new RateLimiter is instantiated everytime. That's why the limit is never reached. The fix for this is quite simple. We have to define the ratelimiter outside of the RateLimiter delegate
.AddStandardResilienceHandler(options => 
{ 
    var limiter = new FixedWindowRateLimiter(new FixedWindowRateLimiterOptions()
    {
        PermitLimit = 2,
        Window = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
    });
    options.RateLimiter.RateLimiter = args 
       => limiter.AcquireAsync(cancellationToken: args.Context.CancellationToken);

});


Update #2

the next challenge is that the RateLimiterRejectedException that is now thrown when the policy is triggered, is not automatically picked up and 'handled' by the retry policy.

This Microsoft Learn material says the following:

The retry pipeline retries the request in case the dependency is slow or returns a transient error.

And in the very next section it details the handled exceptions:


HttpRequestException
TimeoutRejectedException


If you are interested here you can find the related source code.
So, how can we add RateLimiterRejectedException to the current predicate? The ShouldHandle outcome is a ValueTask<bool> so if we await it then we can simple add || args.Outcome.Exception is RateLimiterRejectedException:
.AddStandardResilienceHandler(options => 
{ 
    // Rate limiter
    var limiter = new FixedWindowRateLimiter(new FixedWindowRateLimiterOptions()
    {
        PermitLimit = 2,
        Window = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
    });
    options.RateLimiter.RateLimiter = args 
       => limiter.AcquireAsync(cancellationToken: args.Context.CancellationToken);

    // Retry
    var standardPredicate = options.Retry.ShouldHandle;
    options.Retry.ShouldHandle = async args => await standardPredicate(args) 
       || args.Outcome.Exception is RateLimiterRejectedException;

});

Please make sure that you don't inline the standardPredicate(args). That would make the ShouldHandle recursive and it will shortly fail with a Stack overflow.
Here you can play with a simplified dotnet fiddle application.

Update #3
I was playing a bit with your code when I realized for that you can't use the standard resilience handler to retry for ratelimiter because retry is an inner strategy from the rate limiter perspective.
public static IHttpStandardResiliencePipelineBuilder AddStandardResilienceHandler(this IHttpClientBuilder builder)
{
    ...
    _ = builder.AddResilienceHandler(StandardIdentifier, (builder, context) =>
    {
        ...
        _ = builder
            .AddRateLimiter(options.RateLimiter)
            .AddTimeout(options.TotalRequestTimeout)
            .AddRetry(options.Retry)
            .AddCircuitBreaker(options.CircuitBreaker)
            .AddTimeout(options.AttemptTimeout);
    });
}


That means the rate limiter is the outer most strategy. If every other strategy failed to handle request then it will reach the rate limiter. That's why changing the retry strategy's ShouldHandle caused no retries.
Here we have documented that the strategies registration order does matter.

This compiles, but in my test setup, it doesn't actually restrict the number of outgoing requests to 2/s. I'll see if I can post a minimal example shortly. Is there some concept or other config regarding the rate limiting that needs to be applied on top of this, to actually limit the outgoing rate?

@Daan Sorry my bad, the rate limiter should be defined outside of the RateLimiter delegate.

Thanks Peter, that helps! Though the next challenge is that the RateLimiterRejectedException that is now thrown when the policy is triggered, is not automatically picked up and 'handled' by the retry policy. Do you happen to have a suggestion how to wire these together, in such a way that is preserves and extends the standard retry policy that is already in place?

@Daan I'm currently away from my computer, tomorrow I'll double check how the standard http resilience strategies are defined.

@Daan I've updated my post with your next challenge.

Thanks @PeterCsala, I really appreciate the effort you're putting in answering my question! I'm having a hard time finding a way to diagnose and solve these issues myself. The documentation is a bit scattered and doesn't always provide enough in-depth information (or at least I'm having difficulties finding it).

The next issue I run into is that the RateLimiterRejectedException still isn't handled. The code from your example never seems to retry. If I change the ShouldHandle delegate to ValueTask.FromResult(true), the retry does trigger, but that is not the desired solution obviously. If I debug or try to output the Outcome.Exception, it always appears to be null. My minimal test setup: https://github.com/daanstolp/rate-limiting

@Daan In the provided dotnet fiddle you can see that the retry triggers threetimes so, Polly does its job. I did not try to do the same with AddStandardResilienceHandler. Later this week I will give it a try there as well.

@Daan I've updated my post with a bit disappointing realization that the retry is an inner strategy from the rate limiter perspective.

And there's probably no way to change the order of registrations after the fact? :) So the answer to my original question appears to be: it is not possible to achieve the required rate limiting implementation with the AddStandardResilienceHandler extension. I will have to write my own pipeline to achieve the effect. Thanks for clarifying, much appreciated!

@Daan You can't change the strategies order after the pipeline is built. Unfortunately you can't use AddResilienceHandler and AddStandardResilienceHandler for the same IHttpClientBuilder. You can use only of them.

As a side note Polly does support dynamic reload but it is currently limited to reload strategy options.
